# Visual studios how can I create a non numerical virtual directory in the url

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2013

My project URL on visual studio is http://localhost:63012/ I can change the port number to anything and everything still works, however it does not let me create a non-numerical URL such as http://localhost/myapplication/ . It says unable to create virtual directory. The url  http://localhost:80/ is already mapped to a different folder in IIS. I need a non-numerical port because that is the only way that the Android emulator will recognize the Json code in Visual Studio any suggestions would be great..

Comment: Visual Studio uses IIS Express, you could publish your website to the local IIS server (you have to enable this windows feature first, if not enabled already)

Comment: The number part is the *port*. A virtual directory is something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

when you remove the number, the default port is 80.
You already have IIS installed so it getting full access of port 80 so you have 2 options:

you use the virtual directory inside the custom port on IIS Express like this :

http://localhost:63012/myapplication

or you don't use IIS Express (right click on project, properties, web, server IIS, create virtual directory)

and browse like http://localhost/myapplication